# How many times can you post a PHP $_POST[''] Variable?

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have never been able to echo a $_POST[''] variable more than once. Why is this and what am I doing wrong? Please see my example below.

Page 1: User fills in a small form - for example: Username and Password.

Page 2: (the action of the form): I echo out `$_POST['Username'] and $_POST['Password']`.

Page 3 (the page you are redirected to from Page 2 via `header("Location: page3.php")`: I can't echo out `$_POST['Username'] and $_POST['Password']` here? Why is that?

Comment: POST-variables only exist in the current request. if you want to use it severall times, use *[sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)*. Then it will exist as long as the user doesnt close the browser or you delete the session (e.g. via logout). Acess session vars via $_SESSION

Comment: "include" needed page depending on result you get on Page 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation :

Page 1 : User send data to Page2 by your form

Page 2 : You use the data recieved from POST.

Page 3 : You're not on Page2 anymore and since you haven't save your variable in any way that could be use throught mutiple pages, you cannot access them from here.

A quick example could me that :

```
 Page  1 : FORM

 Page  2 : 
        <?php 
            //Save your data like with a SESSION
              session_start();
              $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['Username'];
              $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['Password'];
            //Display your data
            echo $_POST['Username'].'-'.$_POST['Password']; 
         ?>
Page  3 :
        <?php
           echo $_SESSION['username'].'-'.$_SESSION['password'];
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a data from one page to another

Page 1: submit data to Page 2

Page 2: you not submit the data to page 3 so you can't access in page 3

if you want pass data to page 3 so use

1.url

like `header("Location: page3.php?username=$_POST['Username'] and password = $_POST['Password']")`

another solution is user 'SESSION'

2.session

store your data in session and use in all page

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you only post your data to page2. After you redirect to page3 you will loose all your post-data. if you want to send data to your page3 you woud need to post it again from page2. if you just want your data to appear on page3 you coud send it as $_GET-parameter with the header function like this:

```
$loginname = $_POST["loginname"];
$pw = $_POST["password"];
header("Location: page3.php?loginname=$loginname&password=$pw");
```

Now you can acces your data via $_GET like this:

```
$_GET["loginname"];
$_GET["password"];
```

Note that like this you will send both loginname and password in your url wich can be read and modified so this is not a secure way to send your logindata